# Why do I get "required field is not set" when following the Tutorial: Create an Azure VM cluster with Terraform and HCL?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Tried setting up azure vms using terraform for the first time -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/terraform/create-vm-cluster-with-infrastructure

```
 resource "azurerm_resource_group" "test" {  name     = "acctestrg" 
 location = "West US 2" }

 resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "test" {  name                =
 "acctvn"  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]  location            =
 azurerm_resource_group.test.location  resource_group_name =
 azurerm_resource_group.test.name }

 resource "azurerm_subnet" "test" {  name                 = "acctsub" 
 resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.test.name 
 virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.test.name 
 address_prefix       = "10.0.2.0/24" }

 resource "azurerm_public_ip" "test" {  name                         =
 "publicIPForLB"  location                     =
 azurerm_resource_group.test.location  resource_group_name          =
 azurerm_resource_group.test.name  allocation_method            =
 "Static" }

 resource "azurerm_lb" "test" {  name                = "loadBalancer" 
 location            = azurerm_resource_group.test.location 
 resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test.name

  frontend_ip_configuration {    name                 =
 "publicIPAddress"    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.test.id 
 } }

 resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool" "test" { 
 resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test.name 
 loadbalancer_id     = azurerm_lb.test.id  name                =
 "BackEndAddressPool" }

 resource "azurerm_network_interface" "test" {  count               = 2
 name                = "acctni${count.index}"  location            =
 azurerm_resource_group.test.location  resource_group_name =
 azurerm_resource_group.test.name

  ip_configuration {    name                          =
 "testConfiguration"    subnet_id                     =
 azurerm_subnet.test.id    private_ip_address_allocation = "dynamic"  }
 }

 resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "test" {  count                = 2 
 name                 = "datadisk_existing_${count.index}"  location   
 = azurerm_resource_group.test.location  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.test.name  storage_account_type =
 "Standard_LRS"  create_option        = "Empty"  disk_size_gb         =
 "1023" }

 resource "azurerm_availability_set" "avset" {  name                   
 = "avset"  location                     = azurerm_resource_group.test.location  resource_group_name          =
 azurerm_resource_group.test.name  platform_fault_domain_count  = 2 
 platform_update_domain_count = 2  managed                      = true
 }

 resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "test" {  count                 = 2
 name                  = "acctvm${count.index}"  location             
 = azurerm_resource_group.test.location  availability_set_id   = azurerm_availability_set.avset.id  resource_group_name   =
 azurerm_resource_group.test.name  network_interface_ids =
 [element(azurerm_network_interface.test.*.id, count.index)]  vm_size  
 = "Standard_DS1_v2"

  # Uncomment this line to delete the OS disk automatically when
 deleting the VM  # delete_os_disk_on_termination = true

  # Uncomment this line to delete the data disks automatically when
 deleting the VM  # delete_data_disks_on_termination = true

  storage_image_reference {    publisher = "Canonical"    offer     =
 "UbuntuServer"    sku       = "16.04-LTS"    version   = "latest"  }

  storage_os_disk {    name              = "myosdisk${count.index}"   
 caching           = "ReadWrite"    create_option     = "FromImage"   
 managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"  }

  # Optional data disks  storage_data_disk {    name              =
 "datadisk_new_${count.index}"    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"   
 create_option     = "Empty"    lun               = 0    disk_size_gb  
 = "1023"  }

  storage_data_disk {    name            =
 element(azurerm_managed_disk.test.*.name, count.index)   
 managed_disk_id = element(azurerm_managed_disk.test.*.id, count.index)
 create_option   = "Attach"    lun             = 1    disk_size_gb    =
 element(azurerm_managed_disk.test.*.disk_size_gb, count.index)  }

  os_profile {    computer_name  = "hostname"    admin_username =
 "testadmin"    admin_password = "Password1234!"  }

  os_profile_linux_config {    disable_password_authentication = false 
 }

  tags = {    environment = "staging"  } }
```

Still not able to set up.

Running terraform plan always gives the following error -
Abhisheks-MBP:first abhisheksingh$ terraform plan

Error: "features": required field is not set

As suggested by number of stackoverflow questions, I tried adding providers block with empty features section. I also tried to pin the version down to 2.0.0. However , everytime version 2.8.0 gets downloaded and the same error comes up again. Does anyone know what needs to be done ? This is pretty frustrating for someone who is trying for the first time. What kind of tutorial is that it lets you struggle so much the first time itself.

Abhisheks-MBP:first abhisheksingh$ terraform -v
Terraform v0.12.24
+ provider.azurerm v2.8.0

I even added the following section to the tf file -

> ## Azure Provider/s provider "azurerm" {   version = "=2.0.0"   features {} }

But does not help!!

Why do I get "required field is not set" when following the Tutorial: Create an Azure VM cluster with Terraform and HCL?

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm this tutorial works, I also matched your Terraform and Azure provider versions:

```
Terraform v0.12.24
+ provider.azurerm v2.8.0
```

The error would indicate that Terraform did not find `provider` block specified, and your provided code sample does not set one, so assuming you gave the whole `main.tf` file I'd suggested adding the following block to the top of your `main.tf` file

```
provider "azurerm" {
  version = "2.8.0"
  features {}
}
```

Also please make sure your are in the directory where `main.tf` is located when you initiate `terraform init` and `terraform plan`

I had success with the following `main.tf`

```
provider "azurerm" {
  version = "2.8.0"
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "test" {
  name     = "acctestrg"
  location = "West US 2"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "test" {
  name                = "acctvn"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.test.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "test" {
  name                 = "acctsub"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.test.name
  address_prefix       = "10.0.2.0/24"
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "test" {
  name                = "publicIPForLB"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.test.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
  allocation_method   = "Static"
}

resource "azurerm_lb" "test" {
  name                = "loadBalancer"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.test.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                 = "publicIPAddress"
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.test.id
  }
}

resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool" "test" {
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
  loadbalancer_id     = azurerm_lb.test.id
  name                = "BackEndAddressPool"
}


resource "azurerm_network_interface" "test" {
  count               = 2
  name                = "acctni${count.index}"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.test.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "testConfiguration"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.test.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "dynamic"
  }
}


resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "test" {
  count                = 2
  name                 = "datadisk_existing_${count.index}"
  location             = azurerm_resource_group.test.location
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
  storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  create_option        = "Empty"
  disk_size_gb         = "1023"
}

resource "azurerm_availability_set" "avset" {
  name                         = "avset"
  location                     = azurerm_resource_group.test.location
  resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
  platform_fault_domain_count  = 2
  platform_update_domain_count = 2
  managed                      = true
}


resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "test" {
  count                 = 2
  name                  = "acctvm${count.index}"
  location              = azurerm_resource_group.test.location
  availability_set_id   = azurerm_availability_set.avset.id
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
  network_interface_ids = [element(azurerm_network_interface.test.*.id, count.index)]
  vm_size               = "Standard_DS1_v2"
  # Uncomment this line to delete the OS disk automatically when deleting the VM  
  delete_os_disk_on_termination = true
  # Uncomment this line to delete the data disks automatically when deleting the VM  
  delete_data_disks_on_termination = true
  storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "16.04-LTS"
    version   = "latest"
  }
  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "myosdisk${count.index}"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }
  # Optional data disks  
  storage_data_disk {
    name              = "datadisk_new_${count.index}"
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
    create_option     = "Empty"
    lun               = 0
    disk_size_gb      = "1023"
  }
  storage_data_disk {
    name            = element(azurerm_managed_disk.test.*.name, count.index)
    managed_disk_id = element(azurerm_managed_disk.test.*.id, count.index)
    create_option   = "Attach"
    lun             = 1
    disk_size_gb    = element(azurerm_managed_disk.test.*.disk_size_gb, count.index)
  }
  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "hostname"
    admin_username = "testadmin"
    admin_password = "Password1234!"
  }
  os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = false
  }
  tags = { environment = "staging" }
}
```

Make sure you use `terraform init` to download correct provider version.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are not alone, I got the same error...
if I just copy paste the code from that tutorial I get:
`Error: "features": required field is not set`

What I see is that it does not have a provider block, it should be something like:

```
provider "azurerm" { 
    # The "feature" block is required for AzureRM provider 2.x. 
    # If you are using version 1.x, the "features" block is not allowed.
    version = "~>2.0"
    features {}
}
```

Other tutorials do cover that:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/terraform/create-vm-cluster-module#set-up-authentication-with-azure

Educated guess no one is really reviewing those tutorials.
All you can do is leave them a comment to let them know...

Comment: I tried this earlier as well if you see my question towards the end. I tried it agian and the error does not change!

Comment: On my case as soon as I added the `provider "azurerm"` block to the code, the error changed